# Module project is not declared as war package, but get error 'web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true' in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, war

Module project was declared as war package before in pom.xml, then I removed row `<packaging>war</packaging>`, I can get expected XX.jar successfully when I run command line `mvn install`, however, I'm still get error `web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true` in eclipse.

I have applied 'Force update of snapshot/releases' several times but it's meaningless.

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <name>xxxx</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please post your pom.xml?

Comment: I posted the pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is web service descriptor however there shouldn't be. I didn't find any way I can delete the descriptor I copy all source files to another folder, create another workspace in eclipse and import the project. All works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - maven project that due to some refactoring went from war package to jar.  Was surprisingly difficult to clear the dang marker "web.xml is missing but failOnMissingWebXml is true".

I checked thru the .classpath and .project files - the project in particular had several WST natures that I deleted.  After that, I finally deleted the project from Eclipse **but left the files on disk**, then re-imported the existing maven project into Eclipse. This worked, I think the delete cleared all the hidden metadata.

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue - you need to generate a web.xml file.

Right click on Deployment Descriptor in Project Explorer.
Select Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub.
It will generate WEB_INF folder in src/main/webapp and an web.xml in it.

Thanks

Comment: Downvoted because this is a jar, NOT a war-packaged project.  Adding bogus files is the wrong solution.